# ASP.NET How To Stream File To User

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, httpresponse

Initially I was trying to figure out what the difference is between Response.Close and Response.End, but after doing more googling and research, its clear that I haven't seen a common way a Byte[] gets sent back to the client.  I'll leave the code sample below, but I would like to know what the industry standard is for doing this.

```
Byte[] myBytes = GetReportBytes();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", myBytes.Length.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + this.ReportFileName + GetReportExtension());
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = GetApplicationContentType();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(myBytes);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
//CERT FIX
//HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wouldn't call `Response.Close()` or `Response.End()`.

`Response.End()` will stop the page execution/rendering at that point. No code following `Response.End()` will be run. The response is terminated at that point with no further output added to the stream.

`Response.Close()` is similar to `Response.End()`, but allows code to be executed after it is called (but no further output can be sent in the page response).

`Response.Flush()` will send any remaining response items to the page.

From an [IIS core team member](http://forums.iis.net/p/1152058/1898362.aspx):

> Response.Close sends a reset packet to
>   the client and using it in anything
>   other than error condition will lead
>   to all sorts of problems - eg, if you
>   are talking to a client with enough
>   latency, the reset packet can cause
>   any other response data buffered on
>   the server, client or somewhere in
>   between to be dropped.
>
> In this particular case, compression
>   involves looking for common patterns
>   within the response and some amount of
>   response has to be buffered by the
>   compression code to increase the
>   chance of finding longer repeating
>   patterns - this part that is buffered
>   cannot be sent to the client once you
>   do Response.Close().
>
> In short, do not use Response.Close().

Comment: @Mitch - I'm changing the question a bit for more of a how to stream in general.  I'm not really seeing a standard for this and would like to start there.

Comment: So don't call Response.Close() or Response.End() when streaming a file? Just call Response.Flush() to send the file out of the buffer and end the method?

Comment: Interestingly enough, in the context of a MasterPage the MasterPage footer gets written after your content if you don't call  Response.Close() (or the evil Response.End())