# ZIP all files and then download

Tags: c#, file, api, download

at first I want to convert all the files which are inside one folder as .zip and then download this zipped folder using API and C#.

want to access these files from client side. Client Side I'm using AngularJS and want to download file from the server. I put different- different logic but not working.

Comment: You want to download it through a webpage?  From an FTP server?  Simply move a file on a local harddrive?  What C# code have you already tried?  All of this will help us help you better.  :)

Comment: do it then!
Ok I don't mean to be rude, you just need to start writing some code, and when you're stuck we will help you.
Here is a similar solved question that can give you ideas on how to proceed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670263/asp-net-download-all-files-as-zip?rq=1

Comment: want to access these files from client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 public string MergeFiles(string folder)
    {
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(folder))
        {
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folder);
            foreach (string f in fileEntries)
            {
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(f.Substring(folder.Length));
                    zip.AddFile(f, path);
            }
            zip.Save(folder + "\\files.zip");
        }
        return folder+"\\files.zip";
    }
```

Comment: I'm able to zip all the files but tell me the way I send these files to client side. Client is using AngularJS so, person can download these zipped files.

Comment: You can stream the zip file using Response.Content.Headers.Add("content-disposition",
                  "attachment; filename= \"files.zip\"");  context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/zip");

Answer (score 0):

This is an exapmle of how to download a file on c#

```
 string filename = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Your file path/" + filename));

        Response.End();
```