# When downloading a file using FileStream, why does page error message refers to aspx page name, not file name?

Tags: asp.net, http, file-io

After building a filepath (`path`, below) in a string (I am aware of `Path` in `System.IO`, but am using someone else's code and do not have the opportunity to refactor it to use `Path`). I am using a `FileStream` to deliver the file to the user (see below):

```
FileStream myStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);  
long fileSize = myStream.Length;  
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)fileSize + 1];  
myStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)myStream.Length);  
myStream.Close();  
Response.ContentType = "application/csv";  
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);  
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);  
Response.Flush();  
Response.End();
```

I have seen from: [[ASP.NET How To Stream File To User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736301/asp-net-how-to-stream-file-to-user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736301/asp-net-how-to-stream-file-to-user) reasons to avoid use of `Response.End()` and `Response.Close()`.
I have also seen several articles about different ways to transmit files and have diagnosed and found a solution to the problem (https and http headers) with a colleague.

**However, the error message that was being displayed was not about access to the file at `path`, but the aspx file.**

**Edit:** Error message is:

`Internet Explorer cannot download MyPage.aspx from server.domain.tld`

`Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.`
(page name and address anonymised)

Why is this? Is it due to the contents of the file coming from the HTTP response `.Flush()` method rather than a file being accessed at its address?

Comment: can u plz show message u r getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are sending a file, it is the "page" that contains the header information that describes the file you are sending. The browser still has to download that page, then sees the "attachment; filename=" and gives you the file instead.

So if there is an error, it will be page that is shown as the problem. It's a bit like getting a corrupted email with an attachment, you seen the problem in the email not the attachment itself.

Don't call Response.End();