# ViewBag Value after Response.Close Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, response, viewbag

I have set a `ViewBag`, which is not displayed in `View`. Following is my code :-

```
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("content-dispostion", "filename=text.zip");
Response.Charset = "";
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
      foreach (var item in List)
      {
            zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath("~/" + item.Code.ToString() + ".pdf"), "/");
      }
      zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}

Response.Close();
ViewBag.Message = "Success";
return View();
```

If I `comment` the `Response` Code & Just set `ViewBag` & `return View()` then `ViewBag` value is displayed in `View`.

How to get value of `ViewBag` after `Response.Close()`?

Comment: Should you not set the ViewBag.Message before you close the response? Also, I wouldnt use the ViewBag in this case, I'd use TempData["Message"] = "Success".

Comment: @Derek Before Closing also didn't display it..~

Comment: pls check the link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219701/asp-net-response-close-issue

Comment: Youneed to step through your code, are you exception handling, is the Action dropping out before it can set the Viewbag.. Are you being presented with the new VIew(new request),