# Download PDF in ASP Error on Some Machines

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

I am using this code to generate pdf's to download on an ASP page and the pdf does download properly on some pages but not on all.  Several users are experiencing an error message as seen in the attached image.  Please let me know if you have suggestions on how to fix this problem.  It is sporadic so its been hard to nail down a cause.

```
Public Sub Download(filename As String)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.BufferOutput = False
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filename))
    Response.WriteFile(filename)
    Response.Close()

End Sub
```

[image: error]

Comment: The image got lost along the way.

Comment: @AntonGogolev I fixed that

Comment: The problem is that Response.Close(), it closes the connection abruptly and you should avoid doing that.

Comment: @derloopkat so what should I do there?

Comment: Try Response.Flush(); followed by Response.End(). This problem was reported here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219701/asp-net-response-close-issue

Comment: thanks @derloopkat I am trying that now, will keep you posted.

Comment: @derloopkat it worked, youre the man.  If you want to put it in as an answer I will approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Response.Flush(), followed by Response.End().