# How to download a CSV file from an ASP page after user clicks a button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I basically have put the following into my button click even handler, and it works *mostly* but it also writes out all the html of the page too in the CSV file. Is there a way to stop this?

```
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("pkey,epsn,Cal. Date (UTC),Va Mult, Vb Mult, Vc Mult,Ia Mult, Ib Mult, Ic Mult, Ia Phase, Ib Phase, Ic Phase, CT Rating, CT Type, Cal By");
                Response.ContentType = "application/csv";

                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=EPSn.csv");
                Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sb = new StringBuilder((string)row[0]);
                    for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (row[i] is DBNull)
                            sb.Append(",NULL");
                        else if (i == 2)
                            sb.Append("," + new DateTime((long)row[i]).ToString("G"));
                        else
                            sb.Append("," + row[i].ToString());

                    }
                    sb.AppendLine();
                    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should also have Response.End() after this code: So that no more response is added to the response stream. That may be adding page output to your CSV.

```
sb.AppendLine();
Response.Write(sb.ToString());

Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you start to write the response add.

```
Response.Clear();
```

Add the following at the end of your code.

```
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Kudos the the following question about the best way to end the response.

[HttpResponse.End vs HttpResponse.Close vs HttpResponse.SuppressContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886729/httpresponse-end-vs-httpresponse-close-vs-httpresponse-suppresscontent)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to stop this?

You could clear the response:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
```

Also please [stop rolling your own CSV parser](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp). It's absolutely horrible, I see people continue doing this mistake over and over again.

Comment: sorry I should have added that line, but I do have a response.Clear above the string builder declaration.

Comment: Also try adding `Response.ClearContent();`.

Comment: I added that above the StringBuilder declaration, and that did not work either.

Comment: btw Technically I am not rolling my own, CSV parser, Excel is going to parse it. Im just writing it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the whole problem. You are writing/rolling it :-) And CSV parser doesn't only mean reading. It also includes writing. So whether you are using `string.Split(',')` or `sb.Append(",")` you are equally guilty :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're trying to avoid excel, but this snippet works in my code:

```
    void InitAttachment()
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename= " + this.FileName;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    }
```