# Intermittent 'Unable to download' error in Internet Explorer over SSL Web API

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, ssl, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

We've been banging our heads off our desks over this one, and I'm going to assume this has something to do with the Response headers. The intermittent 'Unable to download' dialog is causing me to guess exactly what the issue is since most of the other issues I've seen seem to be an all or nothing issue.

We are serving PDFs via a SSL-enabled Web API endpoint. The headers being sent back are as follows:

```
resp.Content.Headers.Clear()
resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf")
resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = New ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
resp.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "exported.pdf"
resp.Headers.CacheControl = New CacheControlHeaderValue() With {.Private = True}
```

From what I've read, the Cache-Control header is at the root of this issue. This current solution works intermittently. This is occurring in IE8 and IE10 right now. Any suggestions? Setting in the Internet Options are correct.

Some options I'm mulling are:

1. Setting the MaxAge
2. Setting the Pragma header to Private
3. Setting no-store, no-cache in a specific order for Cache-Control.

Will any of these realistically work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We simply upgraded to Internet Explorer 10 to remedy this problem. I believe this was an issue with the Request headers, but I wasn't using the correct combination to fulfill Internet Explorer 8's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Cache control header should work see the following answer for how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/15687482/482390.

When you say it's intermittent I am not sure if that is on the same browser and a single user or multiple users; we had a similar issue and it was due to some users having a particular setting ("Do not save encrypted pages to disk") checked in Internet Explorer 9. This setting is found under the Advanced Tab of Internet Options, the following article describes your issue how to do modify this setting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2549423.