# End of result from BinaryWrite Flush is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having some problems dealing with downloading a file from the server.
The problem is that the end of the downloaded file is missing.

I have found some indications of other people having similar problems, but nothing that helps me in my problem.

When debugging I have learned that the length of `fileData` is correct, and all data is present in the byte array when calling `BinaryWrite`.
That leaves the `BinaryWrite`, `Flush` or `Close` calls...
I have read about not using `Response.End` or `Response.Close`, for example here:
[HttpResponse.End vs HttpResponse.Close vs HttpResponse.SuppressContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886729/httpresponse-end-vs-httpresponse-close-vs-httpresponse-suppresscontent) and it seems like a probable cause, but what should I use instead (have tried to remove `Response.Close` completely, but that result in too much data output)?

Someone knows what might cause this behaviour, and how to fix it?

EDIT: Just tried with `Response.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";` and it works like a charm!
What is the difference between text/plain and binary/octet-stream that may cause a behavior like this?
It even works without the `Close` call...

MORE EDIT: Seems like compression of Responses was activated on the server-side. Apparently there seems to be an issue with plain text streams when compression is active.

The code I have is:

```
private void DownloadFile(byte[] fileData, string fileName, string fileExtension)
{
    Response.Clear(); 
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + fileExtension);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileData.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.BinaryWrite(fileData);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();

Comment: Tried it, but no dice... Now sure how adding a call to `End` would help, since it has already failed on `Close`... And in my case `End` and `Close` would produce the same since I have nothing more to process after the call.

Comment: hmm, maybe your file is too big. can you try this way?(in the accepted answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650/how-to-implement-a-file-download-in-asp-net

Comment: I managed to find what was causing it... compression of responses was activated on the server-side. This probably caused the stream to fail somehow...

Comment: @jackjop Thanks for time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compression is active on the server-side (IIS) it apparently causes trouble with text/plain streams.

For you with similar problems, try deactivating, it might help!

It surely did for me!