# updating classic asp method, streaming .exe file to user

Tags: c#, asp-classic

I am converting a classic asp page to .net and came across this piece of code:

```
Sub SendBinaryFile(b_FileName)
tool = Server.MapPath("bin/" & b_FileName)
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & b_FileName
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Type = 1
    BinaryStream.LoadFromFile tool
    Response.BinaryWrite BinaryStream.Read
    BinaryStream.Close
    Set BinaryWrite = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have not done this before in .net so I am wondering what is the 'correct way to stream a .exe file to the user?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736301/asp-net-how-to-stream-file-to-user  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596747/download-stream-file-from-url-asp-net

Comment: Not really, the other one is regarding how to form the url to get the file and then stream it, my question is 'what is the standard or best practice!

Comment: There isn't a 'best' way. The way you posted is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot simpler in .Net....

```
tool = Server.MapPath("bin/" & b_FileName)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & b_FileName)
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(tool))
```

Comment: Richard, thanks, do I need to cleanup afterwards, flush anything?  Thanks, Ron.

Comment: You haven't created any objects there, so nothing to tidy :)