# how to make code execute after Response.end

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "name" + ".pdf");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile("~/media/pdf/name.pdf");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
     if (FileExists("/media/pdf/name.pdf"))
     {
         System.IO.File.Delete("D:/Projects/09-05-2013/httpdocs/media/pdf/name.pdf");
     }
```

Here I want to download name.pdf in the browser, and after the download I want o delete that file.But the code execution stops at

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

no code after that line is executed.so my delete function is not working.Is there any work around for this issue?

Comment: put this Code  HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); after Delte(). Response.End() will stop the Page Life cycel Execution in asp.net

Comment: @AKS What background worker?

Comment: @nmat :it was a reply to another comment.I think he had deleted it

Comment: @AkshayJoy already tried it.but the download does not happens after that.as the file does not exists

Comment: @AKS Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736301/asp-net-how-to-stream-file-to-user?rq=1

Comment: @AkshayJoy Yes that worked .changed to  HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HttpResponse.End` (as per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx)) raises a `ThreadAbortException` and as you do no attempt to handle this your method exits.

I'm not sure exactly why you must use End(), but you could put the "cleanup" code in a finally statement.

Comment: changin End() to  HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); helped

Answer (score 5):

```
// Add headers for a csv file or whatever
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.csv")
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

// Write the data as binary from a unicode string
Dim buffer As Byte()
buffer = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(csv)
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)

// Sends the response buffer
Response.Flush()

// Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
Response.SuppressContent = True

// Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe fire some async method (fire and forget style) to delete the file or have a clean-up service on the server to delete all your files after certain time and rule.

Like mentioned about Reponse.End is pretty harsh and final... more details here:
[Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful)

just my thoughts on that... =)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
try this: copy to MemoryStream -> delete file -> download.

```
string absolutePath = "~/your path";
try {
    //copy to MemoryStream
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(absolutePath))) 
    { 
        fs.CopyTo(ms); 
    }

    //Delete file
    if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(absolutePath)))
       File.Delete(Server.MapPath(absolutePath))

    //Download file
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + absolutePath + "\"");
    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray())
}
catch {}

Response.End();
```