# chrome Failed - Network Error

Tags: google-chrome, download

I have an ASP.NET application Hosted on server 2008.
Recently After latest chrome update to 53.0.2785.116m All of my downloads from server get fail.
I tested chrome version 52, firefox and IE! all of them work.
Any idea for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I find the solution.
web servers by default set the "content-length" in header and also most of the browser auto correct the file size if its wrong.
in new version of google chrome (v53) the auto correct doesn't work.
And at the end I had to set "content-length" property in HTTP Context while flushing the file to client.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed it for me.

Comment: @HamidFathi Where did you set the `content-length` property. I have same error posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44337947/1232087). could you please help?

Comment: Note, using either of `Response.Close();` or `Response.End();` will break downloading. Use `Response.Flush();` instead and then the `content-length` header is not required. https://stackoverflow.com/a/736462/481207