# Failed network error while downloading the files from Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I written the below c# code for downloading the attachments in my application, when i run the code i can download the files using Mozilla, internet explorer but this is not working in Google Chrome.

```
string base64FileString = result;
byte[] binaryFile = Convert.FromBase64String(base64FileString);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", Request.QueryString["FILENAME"]));
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.BinaryWrite(binaryFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Can anyone please help me what changes need to do for downloading in Chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Chrome will not open a "file save" window for you if `"application/octet-stream"` is your response from a form.

The content-type should be whatever it is known to be, if you know it. E.g. `"application/pdf"`, `"image/png"` or whatever. See [Complete list of MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types)

See this question [What could keep Chrome from downloading files?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21658/what-could-keep-chrome-from-downloading-files) for more information.

Comment: See also [how to determine a file's MIME type from its file name extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-mime-type-from-filename-extension)

Comment: I used "application/pdf" but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: when i was downgraded my google chrome to older version then the above code is working fine.Is anyone know what changes we need to do for the above code for downloading the file in newer versions of Google Chrome.

Comment: Remove `Response.Close();` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/736462/481207

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `Content-Length` header, but not sure it's effective:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fl = new System.IO.FileInfo(downloadFilePath);
this.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fl.Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

This same issue dreaded me for months. Here is how I solved it.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click on the active server for which your site is running
3. In the "Feature View" scroll down and locate Configuration Editor under "**Server Component**".
4. Under the configuration editor section, there is a dropdown. Go through it and look for **system.applicationHost**
5. Under it, you should find **weblimits**
6. The configuration to change is **minBytePerSecond**. the default value may be 240. Microsoft recommends 500 but this issue of download occurs when user is in a region of slow internet connectivity.
   The fix is setting the value to **0**.
   There may be a side effect to this because it may open your service to **slow loris attack**

NOTE: Per what i have read on the internet so far, i believe this fix is application to IIS > 7.
I mine was IIS 10 so the steps above is for IIS 10.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I still get 'Failed Network error'  Any ideas?  thx