dotnetzip creates empty zip file
I'm using dotnetzip to create and download a zip file from an internal website.  When I run the code on localhost using visual studio, it works great.  Creates a zip file with the contents I'm expecting.  When I publish the code to my test web server, it will create and download a zip file but it's empty.  It is not corrupted.
Response.Clear();
Response.BufferOutput = false;
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    foreach (string incident in incidentListNoDupes)
    {
        incidentFileName = incident + ".pdf";
        try
        {
            zip.AddFile(pdfPath + incidentFileName, "");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do stuff

        }

    }

    zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
}

Response.Flush();

Response.End();

I've attempted to create the zip file on the server and download it from there, and via outputstream, but get the same result; works locally but not server.  It gives no error.  Could it be a permissions issue?
Edit: I tried removing reponse.end() based on a different SO question, but now I'm unable to open the zip file "the compressed file is invalid"

how about
zip.AddFile(Path.Combine(pdfPath, incidentFileName), "");

@Bharat Same result. works local, not server.

A tool like Process Monitor can show you that.

@LexLi should I run that on my client or the web server?

Process Monitor checks which files are accessed by which processes. So, can you figure out where you should run it?

See if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736301/asp-net-how-to-stream-file-to-user/736462#736462 .

@SoftwareDveloper I tried removing response.end().  The file downloads and by the file size I can tell it's not empty, but now when I try to open it, I get the error "The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid"

check the files accessiblity on server, seems like its not accessible or something. intially you can try zipping a simple file or image, if that works then you can proceed with your imp files. meanwhile I'll check if there is any other way for this.
